# Declaring variables outside of a function in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

code at the bottom works flawlessly

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun onDigit (view: View){
        val tvInput = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvInput)
        tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
    }

    fun onClear (view: View){
        val tvInput = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvInput)
        tvInput.text = ""
    }}
```

But I wanna write this line
`val tvInput = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvInput)`
outside of the functions **onDigit** and **onClear** (because it appears two times).

If I put out the line, code looks like;

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val tvInput = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvInput)

fun onDigit (view: View){
    tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
}

fun onClear (view: View){
    tvInput.text = ""
}}
```

But the code didn't work. The app crashes after I'm trying to start it and throws an error [app keeps stopping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgH8F.jpg)

Maybe it's an easy problem but couldn't find the solution therefore thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a global variable first and assign it into onViewCreated() [for Fragment] or onCreateView() or onCreate() functions .

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var tvInput : TextView ? = null
//override this function (Ctrl + O)

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      val view = //Inflate your view here 
      tvInput = view. findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvInput) 
      return view 

}
fun onDigit (view: View){
    tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
}

fun onClear (view: View){
    tvInput.text = ""
}}
```

and then you can use it anywhere

Comment: Yes this is true. If you assign a layout variable in the global space no layout is yet initialized and so your reference would be null. Instead using [@KARUNESH PALEKAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12100652/karunesh-palekar) approach you initialize your reference only when the layout has been created, thus causing no errors.

Comment: You’re mixing up Fragment and Activity.

Comment: That is the reason why i have included it in the bracket that onViewCreated in available only in the fragment and rest two are available  overall.

Comment: Since the property is nullable, you will need to use null-safe calls on it. For an Activity you might as well make it `lateinit` instead. For a fragment, you technically should set it back to null in `onDestroyView` to avoid leaking it. To be pedantic, there is no such thing as “global variable” in Kotlin. All variables are local. What you defined is a member property. It’s not global because it’s inside a class.